# Реализация аукциона

Tags: java, json, spring

Есть веб-сервис, одной из опций которого является аукцион. Есть заявка, исполнение которой можно выиграть на этом аукционе. Установка своей цены(ставки) идёт на уменьшение, тоесть учитывает предыдущую ставку.
Вопрос. Как при установлении своей цены(ставки) отследить возможные изменения предыдущей цены, которые могли быть сделаны в рамках ставки другого пользователя?
 Реализовано все это добро на spring mvc + jsp(html, css, js).
Интересует не сам код, а только принцип. Думал возможно при нажатии кнопки установления цены сразу отдельным запросом проверять актуальность  базовой цены и выводить предупреждение. Не сильно хотелось бы влазить в многопоточность. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Принцип именно такой - попытка обновления цены с проверкой, что текущая цена не изменилась. При непрохождении проверки - сообщение о проблеме. *отдельным запросом проверять актуальность базовой цены и выводить предупреждение* - а смысл? уж лучше сразу `UPDATE ... SET price = @newprice WHERE price = @oldprice` и смотрим `affected_rows()`. Или 1, или 0...

Comment: Спасибо, попробую